# Notepad++ showing null values after crash

Tags: notepad++

I was editing a files in Notepad++ which I saved. Unfortunately I did not close Notepad++ application and PC was powered down due to out of battery. 
When the power was back on, I opened my file and found only `'nul' 'nul' 'nul' 'nul' 'nul'` all over doc.This was a text file i was working on saving xml code in it. However my file is of size 300kb. And the size of 'nul's added is to the same size as the previous length of the document. I tried everything there is no cache copy of this saved also by notepad++, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If your working file had ever been saved, try the answers in http://superuser.com/questions/390204/how-to-restore-a-previous-version-of-file-in-notepad

Comment: @msw - I saved it many times in between.

Comment: same problem here; it has corrupted 2 of my important files

Comment: May I ask which chipset/harddrive you are using ?
I also have the problem of "zero" files after crashes with my Asus Z97-Deluxe Motherboard !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost code lines when Notepad++ crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158616/lost-code-lines-when-notepad-crashed)

Answer (score 23):

Install Recuva. In Recuva Wizard select the folder where the corrupted file is. When it first searches for files, it finds only deleted ones. When the search is over, press "Switch to advanced mode", then "Options". Go to Actions tab, select "Scan for non-deleted files", press OK. Then press "Scan". If you are lucky, you will see your file in the list and will be able to recover it.

Hope it helps. I recovered a style.css file this way.

Comment: You are my savior, I panicked once I saw the null - thinking I had lost over a year of note taking and almost a quarter million words but this managed to recover it all.

Comment: Absolute saviour @KyleLi ! Thank you!!