# Retrieve notepad++ data when system goes down

Tags: php, notepad++

[image: this is the document]I was working on notepad++ file this morning. Suddenly my lap goes down. When I restart laptop and reload the file which I was working on (.php file), I got the code lines as follows:
NUL NUL NUL....

I checked in backup of notepad++ files, but I couldnot retrieve..
What should I do?

Comment: Rewrite it, while doing so press Ctrl+S after a maximum of X words (X -
 paranoiaLevel)

Comment: I saved the document already. I need the saved document. The thing is my notepad++ file is encoded in some format. That's why I could not able to reload

Comment: Have you checked the encoding menu?

Comment: yeah, its encoded in ANSI

Comment: Seems that the file is corrupt - something went wrong while writing it on disk or with the disk itself. Maybe you can try a forensic data recovery... But I think you're lost without a backup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost code lines when Notepad++ crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158616/lost-code-lines-when-notepad-crashed)